# How to speed up Python package DB update for Visual Studio IntelliSense?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

When using Python in Visual Studio every time I install a new package and the DB for IntelliSense has to be updated. Now the problem with this is, that it takes about 20 Minutes each time and that is not acceptable. I took a look at the TaskManager and it showed that Visual Studio is running at 0.4% CPU capacity.
Does anyone know how I can speed this up?

Comment: Hi Miemels, what's your VS version and does this issues happens to all your existing and new python application? Please share the detail steps to reproduce it and i will check it in my side.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I'm using Visual Studio 2017. What I'm doing is simply creating a Python project and then via the Python Environment tab I install a new Package. Then it refreshes for 20 Minutes.

Comment: Hi Miemels, I tried to follow your steps in my VS 2017 15.3.3 and after installed the python package, it not reminder me to update DB. Please re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and if there has update, please click 'Update' button to update, if not, click More-Repair to repair it, then create a new python application to test.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT You were right. Thank you very much. The update did fix it for me.

Comment: Hi Miemels, so glad to hear that the update solved your issue, I added a reply and please mark it when you have free time, that can help other community members to easier search this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your steps in my [VS 2017 15.3.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) and after installed the python package, it not reminder me to update DB. Please re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and if there has update, please click '**Update**' button to update it to the latest version.